# How can I make two divs appear next to eachother and not under eachother?

Tags: html, css

Im still learning html/css therefore I apologize if the code is wrong. I've been doing a replica of a site. There are 4 articles on the down side of the site.
[image]

I've created two but the second one always appears under the first one, even though I've gave the div which wraps it "display: inline-block;". I haven't got to learn flexbox yet, any idea how can I fix this?

```css
.subarticle {
    background: white;
    width: 220px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135%;
    left: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    
    
}

.goodidea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
}

.SOČ {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

.informacie {
    margin-top: -15px;    
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    
}

.far {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}

.read {
    color: orange;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 70px;
    
}

.read:hover {
    background: rgb(241, 221, 184);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <div class="subarticle">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="logo s textom good idea" class="goodidea">
        <div class="informacie">
            <h2 class="SOČ">SOČ</h2>
            
            <p class="datum"><i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i>6.1.2021</p>
            
            <h3>
                Stredoškolská odborná činnosť <br> <br>
                Prekonaj sám seba a ukáž, že máš talent...
            </h3>
            <p class="read">ČÍTAŤ VIAC</p>

         </div>

    </div>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="logo s textom good idea" class="goodidea">
        <div class="informacie">
            <h2 class="SOČ">SOČ</h2>
            
            <p class="datum"><i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i>6.1.2021</p>
            
            <h3>
                Stredoškolská odborná činnosť <br> <br>
                Prekonaj sám seba a ukáž, že máš talent...
            </h3>
            <p class="read">ČÍTAŤ VIAC</p>

        </div>
        </div>    

</div> 


</article>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can read about [CSS flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) so  u can achieve ur aims.

Comment: and in ur case, use `display:flex;` into the parent `.subarticle {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex;` on the parent element and they will be aligned in one row. You will need no more CSS.

CSS:

```
.subarticle{
  display:flex;
}
```

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/YzGjOgP

**FULL CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.subarticle{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <div class="subarticle">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="logo s textom good idea" class="goodidea">
        <div class="informacie">
            <h2 class="SOČ">SOČ</h2>
            
            <p class="datum"><i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i>6.1.2021</p>
            
            <h3>
                Stredoškolská odborná činnosť <br> <br>
                Prekonaj sám seba a ukáž, že máš talent...
            </h3>
            <p class="read">ČÍTAŤ VIAC</p>

         </div>

    </div>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="logo s textom good idea" class="goodidea">
        <div class="informacie">
            <h2 class="SOČ">SOČ</h2>
            
            <p class="datum"><i class="far fa-calendar-times"></i>6.1.2021</p>
            
            <h3>
                Stredoškolská odborná činnosť <br> <br>
                Prekonaj sám seba a ukáž, že máš talent...
            </h3>
            <p class="read">ČÍTAŤ VIAC</p>

        </div>
        </div>    
     </div> 
</article>
```